# Unit normal field on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I have the following problem and I do not know how to prove this. I do know that $a\times b$ is orthogonal to a and b and therefore to $T_pS_1$ but I do not believe that this is all that is required. Any help and explanation would be much appreciated.

Let $ : _1 → _2$ be a local diffeomorphism between two surfaces $_1$ and $_2$ with $_2$ orientable. Let $_2$ be a unit normal field on $_2$.
We define a map $_1 : _1 → R^3$ as follows:

if  ∈ $_1$, we put $ N_1(p) = \frac{a\times b}{\lvert a \times b\rvert}$
where ,  form a basis of $__1$ satisfying $det\left((_)(), (_)(), _2(())\right) >0$

Show that $_1$ is a unit normal field on $_1$.

Comment: What is the definition of "a unit normal field on $S_1$"?

Comment: A function n :$ S_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ st $\forall $ p $\in S_1$, n(p) $\bot$ $T_pS_1$ and $\lvert n(p) \rvert$ = 1

Comment: Any old function?

Comment: Yes, it's clear that $N_1(p)$ is orthogonal to $T_pS_1$ and is a unit vector. That much is elementary. Now what must you show? This is why I asked you for a precise definition. Presumably you need to use all the technical hypotheses given in the exercise.

Comment: What I have managed to note is that, $a\times b$ $\bot a$ and $a\times b$ $\bot b$ and therefore $a\times b$ $\bot$ $<a,b> := T_pS_1$ and $\lvert n(p) \rvert $ = 1 therefore N1 : $S_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined in that way has the structure of a unit normal field, but I am confused because I nor understand, nor use the condition of the positive determinant.

Comment: The definition I was given in class is ; A (smooht) map n :$S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is called a (smooth) normal field on S, if $\forall p \in$ S n(p) $\bot  T_pS_1$ and from there that it is a unit normal field if we add the condition that $\lvert n(p) \rvert$=1

Comment: So, why is your mapping smooth? Maybe start with why it's continuous. And where are you using the fact that $S_2$ is orientable?

Comment: I know that is $S_2$ is orientable and f:$S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ is a diffeomorphism then $S_1$ is orientable

Comment: You know that? I believe that's what you're trying to prove.

Comment: $S_2$ is orientable. That means the tangent-space at every point for $S_2$ has an oriented basis of say n-linear independent elements. The tangent map f has an inverse, because its an isomorphism, because f is a diffeomorphism. f plays the same role like iso's in linear algebra. f therefore has an inverse, which maps one basis to another.

Comment: Every manifold has "an oriented basis" at each point. What is the point of orientability?

Comment: Could you please help me prove that $\frac{a\times b}{\lvert a \times b\rvert}$ is smooth. I am having trouble seeing that.

Comment: Well, you need to start by defining $a$ and $b$ smoothly on some open subset of $S_1$.

Comment: Right but I do not understand what that means, nor how to do it. I am sorry, any help would be much appreciated